# New-ADGroup parameter -Path being trimmed

Tags: powershell, parameters

Not sure if anyone has had this issue before;

I've created a script to create on mass a security groups using a basic foreach blaa blaa construct which works fine for most of the 200+ groups created but am having a issue with about 28 stragglers.

When the script runs it uses a path and name set in a csv file among other things.

When it gets to one of the sec groups that it's having issues with the path keeps getting slightly trimmed at the start of the string and when it goes to create the group it fails as the path is incorrect.

I'm not sure if it's the length of the path or a limit on the variable length?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Nigel Tatschner

```
$FileImport = Import-Csv -Path "c:MyPath.csv"


$TopLevelOU = "TopLevelOU"

foreach ($Obj in $FileImport)
{   

    $ChildTrim = $Obj.PSChildName+","
    $Parent = ($Obj.distinguishedName).TrimEnd()
    $ParentTrim = $Parent.TrimStart($ChildTrim)
    $PathTrim = $ParentTrim+","+$TopLevelOU
    $NameAlter = "GTS" + " - " + $Obj.name

    if ($PathTrim -match "Distribution")
    {
        New-ADGroup -Path $PathTrim -Name $NameAlter -GroupScope "Global" -GroupCategory "Distribution" 
    }
    else
    {
    New-ADGroup -Path $PathTrim -Name $NameAlter -GroupScope "Global" -GroupCategory "Security"
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Also you can read about `New-ADGroup` cmdlet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852261

Comment: Added script as requested

Comment: Can you provide some examples from the CSV files, some that work and some that don't?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but what would seeing the content of the csv file help with? it just contains a set of headers and other information extracted from another domain so I can import them in to ours. I'm doing some trimming as the data needed cleaning up during import. Many Thanks

Comment: All csvs in the world contain _sets of headers and other information_ but _yours_ is the one that needs help. Without seeing what your csv looks like we can't tell what is going wrong(and where).Can you paste the error message here? Redact whatever information you need to.

Comment: Resolved it by changing the way I was timing the content of the csv. user -replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the way I was trimming the information, Used -replace $childtrim,"" instead of $parent.Trimstart($childtrim)